# How can I make slidetoggled 'div' independently from another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

Hy everyone!

I'm beginner in jquery. So I have two div elements. They are slidetoggled. When I open/close one div, the other div also move with that. Yes i see, what happend in the background but do you have any Idea how can I make them independently? Thank you!

```
<body>
    <div id="m1">
        <div id="ms1">
            st1
            <div class="content">
                <ul>
                    <li>dasd</li>
                    <li>fsfs</li>
                    <li>fsfs</li>
                </ul>
            </div>   
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="m2">
        <div id="ms2">
            st2
            <div class="content">
                <ul>
                    <li>dasd</li>
                    <li>fsfs</li>
                    <li>fsfs</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

and the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#ms1").click(function(){
        $("#m1 .content").slideToggle(1000);
    });

    $("#ms2").click(function(){
        $("#ms2 .content").slideToggle(1000);
    });         
});
```

Comment: try using .on click instead of .click .

Comment: Why two divs with same id

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Where?

Comment: What do you mean with _both divs moving_?

Comment: @TusharRaj This is irrelevant here.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I am sorry I read m2 and ms2 are same. May be due HeavyLunchException

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n2a819aa/  This is your fiddle and it seems okay to me

Comment: You need css to stop the movement. Add #m1, #m2 {height: 100px} http://jsfiddle.net/n2a819aa/1/

Comment: Actually, you have a missing closing `div`. Just removed my previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

i have updated the FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/socemspx/2/

```
#m1,#m2{ 
    color:white;
    width:200px;
    cursor:pinter;
    padding:5px 1px 1px 1px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
#m1{ 
    background:blue;
}
#m2{ 
    background:green;
}

.content{   
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #000;
}


<div id="m1">
    <div id="ms1">
    st1
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li>dasd</li>
                <li>fsfs</li>
                <li>fsfs</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="m2">
    <div id="ms2">
    st2
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li>dasd</li>
                <li>fsfs</li>
                <li>fsfs</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ms1").click(function () {
        $("#m1 .content").slideToggle(1000);
    });

    $("#ms2").click(function () {
        $("#ms2 .content").slideToggle(1000);
    });

});
```

Comment: There's no difference apart from adding some colours.

Comment: @ MelanciaUK what i want to show is that toggle is working fine.
some divs are not closed properly so i have updated the fiddle

Comment: If what you wanted to point out is a missing closing `div`, you should post a comment, not an answer. Actually, there's already a comment pointing this out.